# How to wait for job to finish when using jenkins-cli.jar to run a slave job?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson

I have a Jenkins slave ( at localhost:8000 ) and **[I am executing it ( link )](https://gist.github.com/djangofan/5165442)** from a Jenkins Master ( at localhost:8080 ).   The basic idea here is to run the remote job and wait until the job is finished.

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8000 build "Test Suite"
```

Right now, this doesn't wait.  I starts the job on the slave and the Jenkins Master says the task is immediately finished although the slave runs for another 30 minutes.

Does anyone know how I can block or check for a signal on the slave to verify it is finished and get the exit status code of the job?

NOTE: My slave test MUST run on the slave because it won't run from Jenkins master, which runs as a service and doesn't allow permissions to start a webbrowser from the test.  So, I run the slave in a visible console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8000 build "Test Suite" -s
```

Adding the parameter `-s` to the build command should trigger the job and return after job is completed

Comment: I'll try it on Monday and get back to you.  Thanks very much.

Comment: Yes, it worked.  That is pretty strange that -s is used for the URL and then also again.  What is up with that?

Comment: I believe the way this CLI interface is laid out is the order of args matters.  the first -s arg is attached to the CLI (i.e. what server) along with the command you're executing ("build").  The second/trailing -s is specific to the "build" subcommand and as the help doc states:

"-s : Wait until the completion/abortion of the command..."

Answer (score 1):

Each windows application returns an exit code to it's parent. Examine the exit code using a windows batch file. Example:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://127.0.0.1:9090 build "Test Suite" -s
echo The exit code is %errorlevel%
```

On successfull job completion you will get:

```
Completed "Test Suite" #72 : SUCCESS
The exit code is 0
```

Examine some error scenarios (wrong job name, job creates FAILED and so on)

Note: Running master jenkins not as windows service may be more easy.